# If Then for consecutive cells based on value

Tags: excel, vba, cells

I have a row of cells with various values. I am looking to find three consecutive cells that are between 2 specified values and use and If Then to set a condition.

Is there a better way to do this?

```
set Bottom = 275
set Top = 1600

 For i = 4 To LastRow
        Set r1 = Cells(5, i)
        Set r2 = r1.Offset(0, 1)
        Set r3 = r1.Offset(0, 2)
        If r1.Value < Top And r2.Value < Top and r3.Value < Top Then
        'Do something
        Elseif r1.Value > Bottom And r1.Value < Top And r2.Value > Bottom And r2.Value < Top And r3.Value > Bottom and r3.Value < Top Then 
        'Do something
        Else
        'Do something
        End If
Next i
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by doing this a different way?

Comment: to reduce room for error

Comment: What errors are you seeing?  There are syntactical errors in your code as posted.  For example, the `Set` statement is only used with objects.  Are `Bottom` and `Top` objects?  I suspect they are `Longs`

Comment: No matter what you do, you are going to have to test each element, individually, against Top and Bottom. Whether doing it as you have written, or doing it in a loop, or using a separate function (per Eric) is better is a matter of taste.  Personally, I would use a loop and an external function, because the code is shorter and the method can be more flexible.  I don't know which would be faster.  Perhaps Code Review would be a more appropriate place to post this question.

Comment: Your code would never enter in the `ElseIf`. If either `r1.Value` or `r2.Value` or `r3.Value` is higher than `Top` it will ignore the `If` part and check for the conditions in the `ElseIf`, but then you are checking if they are bigger than `Botton` and, again, less than `Top`

Comment: To better explain myself, this is your If: `If r1.Value < Top And r2.Value < Top and r3.Value < Top Then` and this is your ElseIf (hidding unrelevant info for illustration): `Elseif (...) And r1.Value < Top (...) And r2.Value < Top (...) And r3.Value < Top Then`. See the issue?

Answer (score 0):

That's a pretty small code snippet, so it's a little hard to figure out what exactly your code is doing here.  You would almost certainly want to employ a loop to loop through the cells:

[How to loop through a list of data on a worksheet by using macros in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/299036)

I would move the logic that calculates the validity of the data to [function](http://www.fontstuff.com/vba/vbatut01.htm) so that it was something like:

```
Function InValidRange(Value as integer)

  Dim Top As integer
  Dim Bottom as integer
  Top= 1600
  Bottom = 275
  If Value < Top and Value > Bottom Then
    InValidRange = true
  Else
    InValidRange = false
  End If
End Function

If InValidRange(r1.Value) And InValidRange(r3.Value) And InValidRange(r3.Value) then
'Do something
End If
```

Comment: Please see the updated code. That is what I have and Im looking for a better way to determine if 3 consecutive cells are between the specified values and if they are do something.

Comment: The updated code looks generally ok to me.  You would want to do some kind of testing and/or error handling to prevent the case where r1.Offset(0,1) and r2.Offset(0,2) not existing, being empty, etc.  I think it would be easier to read if you used a function to test for the element being between Top and Bottom similar to what I posted in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to try and adapt this code (commented):

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim bottom As Long, top As Long, lastColumn As Long, iCol As Long

    bottom = 275
    top = 1600
    lastColumn = 20 '<-- specify last column index or get it through some function
    For iCol = 4 To lastColumn '<--| loop through columns from 4 to lastColumn
        With Cells(5, iCol).Resize(, 3) '<--| reference three contiguous cells in the same row from current one
            .Select
            Select Case True
                Case WorksheetFunction.Min(.value) < bottom '<--| there's one value too small
                    MsgBox "small!"
                    ' do something
                Case WorksheetFunction.Max(.value) > top '<--| there's one value too big
                    MsgBox "big!"
                    ' do something
                Case Else '<--| all value in range
                    MsgBox "ok!"
                    ' do something
            End Select
        End With
    Next iCol
End Sub
```